# Eclipse IDE: 3rd level keyboard symbol not showing up

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, locale

I am having a problem when trying to print 3rd level keyboard symbols in Eclipse IDE with AltGr + [1-9] buttons. Specifically I am using Lithuanian keyboard layout and whenever I press AltGr + number I get both 1st level and 3rd level symbols printed. Eg., if I hit AltGr + 1, I get the following two symbols printed:

> ą1

('ą' is the 1st level symbol, while '1' is the 3rd level one)

For AltGr + 2 it's as follows:

> č2

('č' is the 1st level symbol, while '2' is the 3rd level one)

and etc

I have tried searching if there were AltGr + number or Ctrl + Alt + number key shortucts but could not find any.
I have tested some other keyboard layouts and found that on other keyboards the 3rd level works as usual and prints only one symbol. However, I would also like to note that with the Lithuanian layout AltGr + E works completely fine and prints a single € symbol.
It is also worth noting that I have encountered the same problem on different machines running Windows 7, Windows XP and Red Hat Linux. This may suggest that a solution must be found inside eclipse. However, I have failed to do that and I would appreciate if somebody could help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should file a bug with Eclipse.

Alternatively, you could try to debug Eclipse yourself. The SWT library is the gateway to low-level methods that interface with the OS and handle keypresses and the like. If you looked at org.eclipse.swt.Control, you could find places to put breakpoints.

To debug Eclipse, you need the Eclipse SDK (which comes bundled with the RCP/RAP edition, i.e. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/indigor). Then you create an Eclipse Application launch target and launch it in debug mode.

But file a bug!